# SQL invalid identifier error.....?

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently working on SSH secure shell code that keeps giving this error code. I've tried changing the table names but still, I get this error. HELP!

Here's what the questions ask:

15. List the product ID, product name, and product price for the product(s) sold in more orders than any any other products (based on number of order occurrences, not the quantity).  Format the price as currency, and use the following column headings:  ProductID, Name, Price.
16. List the category ID, product ID, product name, and product price for the lowest priced product in each category.  Format the price as currency, and use the following column headings:  Cat_ID, Prod_ID, Prod_Name, Price.

Here's what the code with the errors:

```
SQL> --question 15
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT Pro.ProductID as ProductID, Pro.ProductName AS Name, to_char(Pro.ProductPrice,'$99.99') AS Price
  2  FROM Product_mys Pro
  3  WHERE Pro.ProductPrice = (SELECT MAX(Pro.ProductPrice)
  4  FROM OrderDetail_mys Pro);
WHERE Pro.ProductPrice = (SELECT MAX(Pro.ProductPrice)
      *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "PRO"."PRODUCTPRICE": invalid identifier


SQL> 
SQL> --question 16
SQL> 
SQL> SELECT Cat.CatID as Cat_ID,Pro.ProductID as Prod_ID, Pro.ProductName AS Prod_Name, to_char(Pro.ProductPrice,'$99.99') AS Price
  2  FROM Category_mys Cat,Product_mys Pro
  3  WHERE Pro.ProductPrice = (SELECT MIN(Pro.ProductPrice)
  4  FROM OrderDetail_mys Pro);
WHERE Pro.ProductPrice = (SELECT MIN(Pro.ProductPrice)
      *
```

These are the schema tables I'm using for the values

```
CREATE TABLE Dept_mys (
 DeptID     Number(3)       NOT NULL,
 DeptName   VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (DeptID) 
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Commission_mys (
 CommClass  CHAR(1)         NOT NULL,
 CommRate   Number(2,2)     NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (CommClass) 
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Category_mys (
 CatID      Number(3)       NOT NULL,
 catName    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (CatID) 
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE SalesRep_mys (
 SalesRepID NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL,
 SalesRepFName  VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
 SalesRepLName  VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
 DeptID         NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
 CommClass      CHAR(1)         NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (SalesRepID),
 FOREIGN KEY    (DeptID)    REFERENCES Dept_mys,
 FOREIGN KEY    (CommClass) REFERENCES Commission_mys 
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Customer_mys (
 CustID     CHAR(5)         NOT NULL,
 CustFName  VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
 CustLName  VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
 CustPhone  CHAR(10),
 SalesRepID NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (CustID),
 FOREIGN KEY    (SalesRepID)    REFERENCES SalesRep_mys
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Order_mys (
 OrderID    NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
 OrderDate  DATE            NOT NULL,
 CustID     CHAR(5)         NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (OrderID),
 FOREIGN KEY    (CustID)    REFERENCES Customer_mys
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Product_mys (
 ProductID      NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
 ProductName    VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
 CatID          Number(3)       NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (ProductID),
 FOREIGN KEY    (CatID)     REFERENCES Category_mys
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE OrderDetail_mys (
 OrderID    NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
 ProductID  NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
 ProductQty NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL,
 ProductPrice   NUMBER(6,2)     NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (OrderID, ProductID),
 FOREIGN KEY    (OrderID)   REFERENCES Order_mys,
 FOREIGN KEY    (ProductID)     REFERENCES Product_mys
 ) ;
```

Comment: Your products table doesn't have a product price column.

Comment: You're right! How do I do a join statements linking OrderDetail and Product..?

Comment: Your schema looks broken given the queries you're asked to answer. Price doesn't belong in the orders table unless it is variable per order, but your two questions seem to imply that it is fixed. If you do want to join, since you already know that you need to join, you're 90% of the way there already. Give it a shot, post what you've tried if it failed and explain what you don't understand.

Comment: Well, I ran it again with the same error showing. ProductPrice is in OrderDetail but ProductName is in the Product table. I don't know how to do joins. Please help me setup a join for OrderDetail table and Product table

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use `ProductPrice` from `Product_mys` which doesn't have that column.

Comment: How would I go about joining OrderDetail and Product table..?